# What is the purpose of Stack Overflow flair?

Tags: discussion, flair

*You got a flair?* and there are a bunch of styles.

What is the purpose of displaying a [flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) in my website?

Is there any advantage other than just linking to my profile to Stack Overflow?

Is it like a badge or like our current tec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two words: showing off. That's it.

See also: [these](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/nowearn-valuable-flair/) [two](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) SO blog posts.

Answer (score 5):

### Free advertising for them.

### Bragging rights for us.

It's win win.

(Look how flair-tastic my flair is!!!)

[image: Stack Overflow profile for jjnguy at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Comment: That's free advertising for *someone*, but not SO! ;)

Comment: @Gno, it is important to note that I didn't specify who was benefiting.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the non-specific "them".

Comment: When I put the flair on my site, it links *away* from it *to* StackOverflow. So it's definitely free advertising for SO. Free advertising for *me* is when I link the other way round, *to* my site *from* my SO profile.

Comment: I like that song.